# Updating to Spring 2.5.5 causes a javax.servlet.UnavailableException: org.springframework.web.struts.DelegatingTilesRequestProcessor

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, struts

I have been told to update some application from Spring 2.0.8 to Spring 2.5.5. This application is using Struts 1.2.7. Once I change the Spring.jar I get the following exception while loading in JBoss 4.0.5:

```
10:14:57,579 ERROR [[/PortalRRHH]] Servlet /PortalRRHH threw load() exception
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: org.springframework.web.struts.DelegatingTilesRequestProcessor
```

This is defined in the struts-config.xml this way:

```
<controller locale="true">
  <set-property property="processorClass" value="org.springframework.web.struts.DelegatingTilesRequestProcessor"/>
 </controller>
```

I have no clue of what is happening since it works with the old version of Spring and the `DelegatingTilesRequestProcessor` is still available in Spring 2.5.5. I have no previous experience with Struts so if you need anything else to figure what the problem is please ask and I will update the question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. It seems that the Spring 2.5.5  library doesn't have this package: `org.springframework.web.struts`. The older version of Spring that the project was using did have that package. I have downloaded [spring-struts.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/STUVWXYZ/spring-struts.jar.htm) and added it to my project and it works now.